How to set background color of an entire line of text in a TextField in compose on android?
I am trying to make a primitive markdown editor with highlighting, and I am having an issue with highlighting code blocks.
I am using AnnotatedString with TextField to make the editor view. However, I can't figure out any way of setting background color an entire line of text, not just the characters. For example, this is what my app looks like:
https://i.sstatic.net/656e9ImB.png
But what I want it to look like is:
https://i.sstatic.net/lGlgPuS9.png
Notice how light grey background goes all the way to the end, even though there are no characters that fill this space up.
Here is the piece of code responsible for the styling of code blocks:
                    withStyle(
                        style = SpanStyle(
                            fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
                            background = colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                            color = colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
                        )
                    ) {
                        append("```")
                        index += 3
                        while (index < value.length && !value.startsWith("```", index)) {
                            append(value[index])
                            index++
                        }
                        append("```")
                        index += 3
                    }

Here is how I apply the AnnotatedString style to the TextField:
  TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        visualTransformation = {
            TransformedText(
                MarkdownProcessor(value, defaultColorScheme),
                OffsetMapping.Identity
            )
        }
    )

Can I highlight an entire line? What would be the appropriate way to implement this kind of behaviour, even if not using AnnotatedString?
Edit: I want to set the background color of specific lines, not the entire TextField.

You don't need AnnotatedString for this task. Instead, use drawBehind to draw rectangles in the background.
Here's a solution:
In the code below, I calculate the list of rectangles to be drawn based on the number of quoted sections the user types.
I use regex to find the start and end positions of each pair of quotes. You can use your custom parser instead.
Inside onTextLayout, you can compute the x/y position of the rectangles based on the position index of the quotes returned by the regex.
@Composable
@Preview
fun App(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

    var rects by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf(Rect.Zero)) }

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .drawBehind {

                // expand list of rects to fill max width
                val rs = rects.map { rect ->
                    rect.copy(
                        right = size.width,
                    )
                }

                rs.forEach { rect ->
                    drawRect(
                        color = Color.Yellow,
                        topLeft = rect.topLeft,
                        size = rect.size
                    )
                }
            },
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { newValue -> value = newValue },
        singleLine = false,
        onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->

            val rs = mutableListOf<Rect>()

            val matchesPairs = parseText(value.text)

            matchesPairs.forEach { (startIndex, endIndex) ->

                val startLine = textLayoutResult.getLineForOffset(startIndex)
                val endLine = textLayoutResult.getLineForOffset(endIndex)

                highlightRangeLine(
                    textLayoutResult = textLayoutResult,
                    startLine = startLine,
                    endLine = endLine
                ) { rect ->
                    rs.add(rect)
                }
            }

            rects = rs
        }
    )
}

/**
 * Parses the input text to find all occurrences of text enclosed by triple quotes (`"""`)
 * and returns a list of pairs representing the start and end indices of these occurrences.
 */
fun parseText(text: String) : List<Pair<Int, Int>> {

    val regex = "\"\"\"((.|\\n)*?)\"\"\"".toRegex()

    val matches = regex.findAll(text)

    val outList = mutableListOf<Pair<Int, Int>>()

    for (match in matches) {
        val startIndex = match.range.first
        val endIndex = match.range.last

        outList.add(startIndex to endIndex)
    }

    return outList
}


/**
 * Highlights a range of lines in a text layout by providing a start and end line numbers.
 *
 * @param textLayoutResult The layout result of the text to be highlighted.
 * @param startLine The index of the start line to be highlighted (zero based index).
 * @param endLine The index of the end line to be highlighted.
 * @param onResult A callback function that receives the resulting Rect representing the highlighted area.
 */
fun highlightRangeLine(
    textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult,
    startLine: Int,
    endLine: Int,
    onResult: (Rect) -> Unit
) {

    val startOffsetX = textLayoutResult.getLineLeft(startLine)
    val startOffsetY = textLayoutResult.getLineTop(startLine)

    val endOffsetX = textLayoutResult.getLineRight(endLine)
    val endOffsetY = textLayoutResult.getLineBottom(endLine)

    onResult(Rect(
        left = startOffsetX,
        top = startOffsetY,
        right = endOffsetX,
        bottom = endOffsetY
    ))
}

Demo


You can try the modifier to fill the color of the background to the entire line something like below.
TextField(
        value = annotatedString,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Gray),
        onValueChange = this,
        visualTransformation = {
            TransformedText(
                MarkdownProcessor(value, defaultColorScheme),
                OffsetMapping.Identity
            )
        }
    )


Thank you, but that is not what I am actually trying to do. I want to make specific lines in a text to have specific background color, not set the color for the entire TextField. I will update the question to clarify that.
